# Do I need both a local and global memory barrier when writing form local memory to global

Tags: opencl

In my kernel, each thread writes to a region in local memory, and then they 
copy from local memory to global memory. Global memory is never read in the kernel, only written to. But, the local memory buffer is subsequently written to after global copy is finished.

Do I need a global memory barrier as well as a local memory barrier after my copy code, or just a local memory barrier:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need a global memory barrier as well as a local memory barrier after my copy code, or just a local memory barrier?

It depends. Without code, it's difficult to answer your question.

> In my kernel, each thread writes to a region in local memory, and then they copy from local memory to global memory.

I can't answer for your precise case without seeing code, but there's basically only two scenarios:

1. Work items read from the same memory they wrote to (data is *not* shared across work items): a memory barrier is **not required**.
2. Work items read from memory written to by another work item. (data is shared across work items): a memory barrier is **required**.

> Global memory is never read in the kernel, only written to.

Then you do not need a global memory barrier. Barriers are required when you need ordering of operations between readers and writers. If there are no readers (or no writers), then barriers are superfluous.

Comment: Thanks. I did some research, and what you are referring to in scenario #1 is called "wave synchronous" programming. Unfortunately, this approach seems to be deprecated, due to newer hardware that can merge work items, thus mixing work items from different wave fronts.  See this AMD opencl thread : http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/166895.  But your point about not needing a global memory barrier is very useful: I have removed it and replaced with local memory barrier.

Comment: So, if you remove the part about wave synchronous programming and just leave the part about not needing global memory barrier, then you have indeed answered the question for full marks !

Comment: I think the problem arises when two work items from different wave fronts are processed on the same hardware compute unit. In which case one would need a memory barrier.  I've submitted a question along these lines to the AMD OpenCL user group.....

Comment: I have reworded scenario 1. But still, this has nothing to do with work item merging.

Comment: Forget about hardware and wavefronts. Simply follow the rules, if memory is not reused, then no need for barrier, if it is reused in different work-items, then put a barrier to ensure no one writes before the other reads. OpenCL is hardware agnostic (unless you want to optimize the code)